# Doctrine autogenerated migration fails to recognize foreign key constraints

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

When creating a migration via the command `doctrine:migrations:diff` I get a migration which cannot be executed afterwards.

I have the following scenario:
I got 2 entites (`parent` and `child`) with a `many to many` relation between each other. So doctrine generated a mapping table for it `parents_childs`. Currently those 2 entiteis have the `id` as integer, now I want to change the type to a `bigint`.

When I create the migration I get something like this:

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE child CHANGE id id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE parent CHANGE id id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE parents_childs CHANGE parent_id parent_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, CHANGE child_id child_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL');
```

On execution of the migrations:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of
>   './symfony_dev/#sql-379_34' to './symfony_dev/oauth_client' (errno:
>   150)

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS ;` gives me the following message for the constraint errors:

> ------------------------ LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>   ------------------------ 150218 14:28:19 Error in foreign key constraint of table my_db/parents_childs: there is
>   no index in referenced table which would contain the columns as the
>   first columns, or the data types in the referenced table do not match
>   the ones in table. Constraint: ,   CONSTRAINT "FK_98FFA0B4D395B25E"
>   FOREIGN KEY ("parent_id") REFERENCES "parents" ("id") The index in
>   the foreign key in table is "PRIMARY" See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

Parent entity definition:

```
AcmeBundle\Entity\Parent:
    type: entity
    table: parent
    id:
        id:
            type: bigint
            unique: true
            nullable: false
            generator:
                strategy: CUSTOM
            customIdGenerator:
                class: 'MyCustomIdGenerator'
            options:
                unsigned: true
    fields: ...
    manyToMany:
        parents:
            targetEntity: AcmeBundle\Entity\Childs
            joinTable:
                name: parents_childs
                joinColumns:
                    parent_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    child_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                        unique: true
            cascade: [remove, persist]
            orphanRemoval: true
            inversedBy: parents
```

Child entity defintion:

```
AcmeBundle\Entity\Child:
    type: entity
    table: child
    id:
        id:
            type: bigint
            unique: true
            nullable: false
            generator:
                strategy: CUSTOM
            customIdGenerator:
                class: 'MyCustomIdGenerator'
            options:
                unsigned: true
    fields: ...
    manyToMany:
        parents: 
            targetEntity: AcmeBundle\Entity\Parent
            mappedBy: parents
```

Dropping the foreign keys, executing the updates and the adding it again would work, tough I actually don't want to do it manually because it also affects a lot more tables.
So Iam now not sure if Doctrine is just not capable of recongizing the foreign keys properly or if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Why don't you modify your migration class to drop the foreign keys and recreated it ?

Comment: I was thinking that the migration lib is capable of properly resolving its defined relations. Still my first project with doctrine and its migration lib, so I wanted to make sure definitions are correct and the lib is just not yet capable of resolving such a thing, before adapting things myself.